# Is START_FILE a GHC pragma?

Tags: haskell

**Who could provide information regarding** `START_FILE` **pragma?**

The is no word about `START_FILE` in [GHC Pragmas Documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.2.2/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#pragmas). Nevertheless it seems to be widely used [[1]](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/Simple%20examples#files), [[2]](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/snoyberg/library-documentation/resourcet#what-is-resourcet), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhaskell%5D%20start_file).

Unfortunately `ghc 8.2.2` does not compile following code[[1]](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/Simple%20examples#files).

```
{-# START_FILE main.hs #-}
main = readFile "file.txt" >>= putStr

{-# START_FILE file.txt #-}
Hello, world!
```

Comment: A list of GHC pragmas can be found [here](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/pragmas.html)

Comment: @AJFarmar, where exactly does your link explain the ```START_FILE``` pragma?

Comment: @RobertK It doesn't, that's why I linked it.

Comment: @AJFarmar, i think the comment is a little unclear. You could have pointed out that it's not present in the list of GHC pragmas, and must therefore be defined somewhere else. Your comment (imo) implies 'look here for an explanation'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pragma is used by `stack` templates. You can specify multiple files inside single file with extension `.hsfiles` by separating files with `{-# START_FILE #-}` pragma.

`stack new PACKAGE_NAME myfiles.hsfiles` will create those files (and all directories automatically) according to your layout, if `myfiles.hsfiles` contains:

```
{-# START_FILE {{name}}.cabal #-}
name:                {{name}}
version:             0.1.0.0
```

or

```
{-# START_FILE package.yaml #-}
name:                {{name}}
version:             0.1.0.0
```

See some examples in this repository:

- https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack-templates

Answer (score 8):

No, this is an extension specific to [School of Haskell Markdown](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/how-to-use-the-school-of-haskell/soh-markdown). It's used to provide several "files" in a single Markdown code block.

It's not "widely used" outside of School of Haskell for that reason. When reading such code snippets, simple treat everything after a `START_FILE` pragma as if it was in a file with the name indicated as the parameter (if it indicates a format like `BASE64` you need to put the decoded bytes into the file instead).

Comment: i had a START_FILE file.json and I fixed it by pulling this out into a separate file